# Adding ArrayList to Queue that is nested within a Map

Tags: java, collections

A paraphrasing of the assignment: 
Using only the Collections Framework, write a program that allows the user to buy and sell a stock. I am NOT permitted to use user defined classes.

The stock needs to have a 3 character String to denote the stocks name, an integer amount of said stock, and the price each of said stock was sold at.

If the user has purchased two instances of stock from the same company, the stock bought first is sold first. First in First out.

I have tried to create a map with a String Key and a Queue with a nested ArrayList as the value. I want to push an ArrayList with the Stock Price and Stock Amount into the Queue. I figured that the Queue being FIFO would be perfect for keeping track and working with lots of purchases under the same stock name. The String key would be the stock name and all of its purchases would be recorded in order under it.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a way to actually get to the queue without a) overwriting whatever was already in it or b) being limited to one instance of a Queue that can't be tied to a stock name.

It seems I need multiple separate instances of a Queue, each under a different String key, but I have no idea how that can be implemented correctly without user defined classes.

You can see other attempts with nested collections in the provided code. All of them are limited by the fact that I am missing something about collection navigation or maybe my understanding of collections is just flawed in general.

```
public static void buy( Map<String, Queue< ArrayList<Integer> >> stockInfo, Queue< ArrayList<Integer> > stockQueue ) {
    System.out.print("Please enter a set of three characters: ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    var stockName = scanner.nextLine();

    while (stockName.length() != STOCK_NAME_COUNT) {
        System.out.printf("Invalid number of characters: %d \n", stockName.length());
        System.out.print("Please enter a set of three characters: ");
        stockName = scanner.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.print("Please enter number of stocks: ");
    var stockNumber = scanner.nextInt();
    while (stockNumber <= 0) {
        System.out.printf("Invalid stock amount: %d \n", stockNumber);
        System.out.print("Please enter number of stocks: ");
        stockNumber = scanner.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.print("Please enter stock price: ");
    var stockPrice = scanner.nextInt();
    while (stockPrice <= 0) {
        System.out.printf("Invalid price: %d \n", stockPrice);
        System.out.print("Please enter stock price: ");
        stockNumber = scanner.nextInt();
    }

    ArrayList<Integer>shares=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    shares.add(stockNumber);
    shares.add(stockPrice);
    stockQueue.add(shares);
    stockInfo.put(stockName, stockQueue);
}

...

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Set<String> stockNames = new HashSet<String>();
    //Set<Queue< ArrayList<Integer> >> StockInfo = new HashSet<Queue< ArrayList<Integer> >>();

    Map<String, Queue< ArrayList<Integer> >> stockInfo = new LinkedHashMap<String,Queue< ArrayList<Integer> >>();
    Queue< ArrayList<Integer> > stockQueue = new LinkedList< ArrayList<Integer> >();

    //Set<Queue< ArrayList<Integer> >> stockInfo = new HashSet<Queue< ArrayList<Integer> >> ();

    //Queue< ArrayList<Integer> > stockInfo = new LinkedList< ArrayList<Integer> >();

    var selection = menu("Choose option: ");

    while (selection != 'E'){
        if (selection == 'B'){
            buy(stockInfo, stockQueue);
            System.out.println(stockInfo);
        } else {
            //sale(stockInfo);
        }
        selection = menu("Choose option: ");
    }

    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}
```

> a. Buy (B or b)
>
> b. Sale (S or s)
>
> c. Exit (E or e)
>
> Choose option: b
>
> Please enter a set of three characters: asd
>
> Please enter number of stocks: 120
>
> Please enter stock price: 10
>
> {asd=[[120, 10]]}
>
> a. Buy (B or b)
>
> b. Sale (S or s)
>
> c. Exit (E or e)
>
> Choose option: b
>
> Please enter a set of three characters: asd
>
> Please enter number of stocks: 100
>
> Please enter stock price: 14
>
> {asd=[[120, 10], [100, 14]]}
>
> a. Buy (B or b)
>
> b. Sale (S or s)
>
> c. Exit (E or e)
>
> Choose option: b
>
> Please enter a set of three characters: asd
>
> Please enter number of stocks: 120
>
> Please enter stock price: 10
>
> {asd=[[120, 10], [100, 14], [120, 10]]}
>
> a. Buy (B or b)
>
> b. Sale (S or s)
>
> c. Exit (E or e)
>
> Choose option: b
>
> Please enter a set of three characters: qwe
>
> Please enter number of stocks: 50
>
> Please enter stock price: 13
>
> {asd=[[120, 10], [100, 14], [120, 10], [50, 13]], qwe=[[120, 10],
>   [100, 14], [120, 10], [50, 13]]}
>
> a. Buy (B or b)
>
> b. Sale (S or s)
>
> c. Exit (E or e)
>
> Choose option: e
>
> Goodbye!

I'm not getting syntax errors, I'm unsure if the logic I have in mind is possible with my current toolset.

If you look at my output you can see that my Queue of ArrayLists is changed across every String key. I know why this is, but if I declare a new instance of a queue in my function it will overwrite what I already have under that key.

Answer (score 0):

In your `buy()` method, you are always overwriting the queue in the map. You need to attempt to retrieve the existing queue first (otherwise make a new one), and then modify it when necessary:

```
ArrayList<Integer>shares=new ArrayList<Integer>();
shares.add(stockNumber);
shares.add(stockPrice);

// this retrieves the existing queue, or creates and stores a new one if there wasn't one already
Queue<ArrayList<Integer>> stockQueue = stockInfo.getOrDefault(stockName, new LinkedList<ArrayList<Integer>>());

stockQueue.add(shares);
```

Then you can remove this line: `stockInfo.put(stockName, stockQueue);` since the `getOrDefault()` method puts the newly created queue in the map for you.

You will need to remove the stockQueue parameter from your `buy()` method signature.